# UIInterfaceOrientation is initialising over and over again

Tags: ios, initialization, uiinterfaceorientation

I've been tackling this for quite a while and really need some help. I have a tutorial view that shows on start up. I have images for portrait and landscape, all I need it to do is when the device is rotate, selected the right image.

I know I'm missing something simple. But here's my code and I would appreciate some help.

```
- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification{
[self adjustViewsForOrientation:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]];
}

- (void) adjustViewsForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation) orientation {
if (IS_IPAD()) {


if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){

    self.searchPage = [LTutorialPage page];
    self.searchPage.title = MY_LOCALIZED_STRING(@"search_tutorial_label_1", nil);
    self.searchPage.bgImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"didactitiel-iPad-port01"];


    self.searchTutr = [[LTutorialView alloc] initWithFrame:rootView.bounds andPages:@[self.searchPage]];

    self.searchTutr.pageControl.hidden = YES;

    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [btn setFrame:CGRectMake((screenWidth-10), 30, 50, 50)];
    [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Close.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    self.searchTutr.skipButton = btn;
    [self.searchTutr setDelegate:self];
    [self.searchTutr showInView:rootView animateDuration:0.3];
    }

    else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){
    self.searchPage = [LTutorialPage page];
    self.searchPage.title = MY_LOCALIZED_STRING(@"search_tutorial_label_1", nil);
    self.searchPage.bgImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"didactitiel_iPad_land01"];


    self.searchTutr = [[LTutorialView alloc] initWithFrame:rootView.bounds andPages:@[self.searchPage]];

    self.searchTutr.pageControl.hidden = YES;

    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [btn setFrame:CGRectMake((screenWidth-10), 30, 50, 50)];
    [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Close.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    self.searchTutr.skipButton = btn;
    [self.searchTutr setDelegate:self];
    [self.searchTutr showInView:rootView animateDuration:0.3];

    }
  }
}
```

So what is happening at the moment, is that every time the device is rotated it keeps adding tutorials views. So if the device is rotated 5 times, it adds 5 views.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you puzzled by this? Your rotation handling code creates and adds a new `LTutorialView` every time it is called. Is your question why this is happening or is your question how to change your code so reuse the 1st view you add?

Comment: @rmaddy my question is how to change your code so reuse the 1st view I add?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following instead of registering for notifications?

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration;
```

or even;

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation;
```

Comment: Doesn't work, still has the same behaviours, just keeps adding a view for every rotation.